# Autohotkey: Identify Google Chrome vs Google Chromium

Tags: google-chrome, autohotkey

I can't seem to figure this out

On autohotkey, there's [documentation](https://autohotkey.com/docs/misc/WinTitle.htm#ahk_pid) on how to identify a window / program running.

Google Chrome and Google Chromium both use the same `ahk_class` and the same .exe name of `chrome.exe`

How does one use something like `winTitle` or `winGet` to distinguish the difference? I tried looking into PID values but they don't seem to be consistent.

**EDIT** via WinSpy++

Using winspy++, I ran a simple experiment. 2 Chromium Windows and 2 Chrome Windows so I can have a control group. Differences:

- INSTANCE HANDLE: Chrome shows `0F2C0000`, Chromium shows `A2820000`
- Process ID: Chrome shows `00003528  (13608)`, Chromium shows `00001B74  (7028)`
- Thread ID: Chrome shows `00003524  (13604)`, Chromium `00000220  (544)`

Comment: What info shows Window Spy if you open a new tab or the same page/file in both browsers?

Comment: i updated the question to include what I saw on winspy

Comment: ID values are not constant. They change each time the programs run. Try to find out distinct differences between both programs (in WinTitle, WinText or ahk_exe Process Name/PATH).

Comment: Is there a tool similar to winSpy to check these things, or do I have to use a ahk script  to check these items

Comment: Window Spy is included with AutoHotkey. Launch it from a script's tray-icon menu or the Start Menu.

Comment: ah okay I thought "Winspy++" and "Windows Spy" were the same thing. I updated the information. I see now that the only thing you can distinguish them is the "WinTitle"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case you have two possibilities to distinguish between the two programs:

(1) Using SetTitleMatchMode 2 and the part of the title that all windows of this program have in common:

```
SetTitleMatchMode 2
If WinExist("- Chromium")
    WinActivate
```

(2) Using "[ahk_exe Path](https://autohotkey.com/docs/misc/WinTitle.htm#ahk_exe)":

```
If WinExist("ahk_exe full_path_of_the_executable_chrome.exe")
    WinActivate
```

Comment: Google chrome is `C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe` and chromium is `C:\Users\user\Downloads\chrome-win32`. Took me awhile to find chromium, had to go to taskmanager → details → chrome.exe (chromium) → open file location

Answer (score 1):

To get the full path of the active window process use this:

```
F1::
    WinGet, Path, ProcessPath, A
    MsgBox, %Path%
return
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Windows Spy (came with autohotkey). Is not the same as winspy++

To access Windows Spy found here:

[image]

Differences are found in `WinTitle`

[image]

Comment: Last question: In wich directory is each program intalled? Try to find the full path of both executables for using "[ahk_exe Path](https://autohotkey.com/docs/misc/WinTitle.htm#ahk_exe)" to identify each program window.

Comment: can ahk actually grab the pathname for me? I tried `F14:: MsgBox, ahk_exe Path` doesn't work.

Comment: See my next answer,